# How to find critical F-Value?

Tags: statistics

So for a problem in the book I'm using I need to find $F_{0.025,10,11}$ and $F_{0.025,11,10}$

So in my book I used the F-distribution table to help me find

$F_{0.025,10,11} = 3.53$

But how do I find

$F_{0.025,11,10} = \text{???}$

My book only has degrees of freedom in the numerator go from 1-10, then 12, 15, $20,$ etc. to infinity completely skipping 11. Other tables I find on google have the same issue. So how do I calculate $F_{0.025,11,10} = \text{???}$

Is there another way to do so without a table that doesn't involve using a programming language like R?

(I can't find the F-distribution tag, so I'm just tagging this under statistics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $F\sim F_{10,11}$ and $G\sim F_{11,10}.$

Then $\Pr(F>3.525672) = 1 - 0.025.$

The distribution of $1/G$ is the same as the distribution of $F.$ Suppose $\Pr(G> a) = 1 -0.025$ and you want to find $a.$ So $\Pr(1/G < 1/a) = 1-0.025.$ You can find $1/a$ in the table for $F_{10,11}$ and then takes its reciprocal.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think I understand it a little better now, but what would you do if you had something like $F_{0.01,25,27}$ where $25$ AND $27$ aren't listed as degrees of freedom in the numerator in the F distribution table. How would you do something like this?

Comment: @WillMeForward : I can think of three possibilities: Use software (that's what I would do) or find a far more extensive book of tables (60 years ago these existed; nowadays a librarian might have to dig it up from a storage trunk in the sub-sub-basement) or interpolate.